# Microphone Recognized, Selected, but No Sound Showing or Input with Recording

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording

Recently picked up Shure MV7 USB Microphone. Plugged it in and recognized by system.

Microphone flash a bit then all lights go green, gain shows it's about mid level on the microphone, buttons on mic work fine.

Go into settings, check input, microphone selected, but no sound bard showing when I speak.
[image]

Here's a shot of the internal mic with sound bars:
[image]

Anyone an audio wizard out there that can help me out?

Oddly when plugged in it hijacks audio output too.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too late, but I also had this issue and using PipeWire solved it.

It seems related to PulseAudio doing something funny that upsets the mic and makes it restart. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1295311

I used this PPA: https://github.com/pipewire-debian/pipewire-debian#1-ppa-configuration

You will probably have to disable the PulseAudio service and restart.