# Shure MV7 USB Microphone seems to work with Thinkpad but not XPS

Tags: drivers, usb, pulseaudio

I have two Linux laptops. Both are running Kubuntu 20.04.2 and are using a 5.10 kernel. One laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad T14s AMD, and the other is a Dell XPS 13. Both have pulseaudio 13.99.1 installed.

I also have a Shure MV7 USB microphone and two different docks; one is USB-C, the other is a TB3 dock that falls back to USB-C (the T14s AMD doesn't support TB3, the XPS does).

Using either dock, the Thinkpad is able to work with the microphone. Using either dock, the XPS 13 is unable to work with the microphone. A MacBook Pro having TB3 does work with the microphone using either dock.

Here is the dmesg output from the working Thinkpad:

```
[18915.145402] usb 4-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[18915.321247] usb 4-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=14ed, idProduct=1012, bcdDevice= 0.02
[18915.321253] usb 4-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=128
[18915.321255] usb 4-1.3: Product: Shure MV7
[18915.321257] usb 4-1.3: Manufacturer: Shure Inc
[18915.770689] hid-generic 0003:14ED:1012.0013: hiddev0,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Device [Shure Inc Shure MV7] on usb-0000:06:00.3-1.3/input3
[18915.781579] input: Shure Inc Shure MV7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.3/4-1.3:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.0014/input/input44
[18915.841698] hid-generic 0003:14ED:1012.0014: input,hidraw8: USB HID v1.11 Device [Shure Inc Shure MV7] on usb-0000:06:00.3-1.3/input4
[18916.649623] retire_capture_urb: 203 callbacks suppressed
```

Here is the `lsusb` output from the working Thinkpad:

```
Bus 004 Device 016: ID 14ed:1012 Shure Inc. EMV Smartcard Reader
```

Here is the dmesg output from the non-working XPS:

```
[56983.419316] usb 5-2.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 116 using xhci_hcd
[56983.577231] usb 5-2.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=14ed, idProduct=1012, bcdDevice= 0.02
[56983.577237] usb 5-2.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=128
[56983.577240] usb 5-2.1.4: Product: Shure MV7
[56983.577242] usb 5-2.1.4: Manufacturer: Shure Inc
[56983.607384] hid-generic 0003:14ED:1012.03C9: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Shure Inc Shure MV7] on usb-0000:04:00.0-2.1.4/input3
[56983.608569] input: Shure Inc Shure MV7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.03CA/input/in
put508
[56983.667617] hid-generic 0003:14ED:1012.03CA: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Shure Inc Shure MV7] on usb-0000:04:00.0-2.1.4/input4

... a few seconds pass ...

[56986.435299] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-32)
[56986.443559] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.451594] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.460171] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.468548] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.477551] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.485375] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.493197] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.501384] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.509453] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.518465] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.526489] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.534350] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.542324] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.550625] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.559931] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.568032] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.576003] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[56986.576367] usb 5-2.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 116
[56986.576411] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.576675] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.577389] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.577419] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.577445] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.577601] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.577740] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.578196] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.578223] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.578247] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
[56986.578371] usb 5-2.1.4: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)

... device appears again immediately ...

[56986.915092] usb 5-2.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 117 using xhci_hcd
[56987.069247] usb 5-2.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=14ed, idProduct=1012, bcdDevice= 0.02
[56987.069251] usb 5-2.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=128
[56987.069254] usb 5-2.1.4: Product: Shure MV7
[56987.069256] usb 5-2.1.4: Manufacturer: Shure Inc
[56987.101511] hid-generic 0003:14ED:1012.03CB: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Shure Inc Shure MV7] on usb-0000:04:00.0-2.1.4/input3
[56987.102673] input: Shure Inc Shure MV7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.03CC/input/in
put509
[56987.159557] hid-generic 0003:14ED:1012.03CC: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Shure Inc Shure MV7] on usb-0000:04:00.0-2.1.4/input4
```

Here is the `lsusb` output from the non-working XPS:

```
Bus 005 Device 014: ID 14ed:1012 Shure Inc.
```

Any ideas on how I can get the microphone working with the XPS 13? Plugging it in using a basic USB-A to USBC adapter also does not work.

Note that the XPS draws 45W of power, while the Thinkpad draws 65W, so I don't believe the issue is that the dock cannot power both the XPS and the mic simultaneously.

**Update 2021-02-27:**

I updated the kernel on the XPS to 5.11 but that didn't help.

Here's a bunch of output from various commands. For most of them I removed entries that weren't related to the MV7.

`/proc/asound/cards`

Working Thinkpad:

```
 5 [MV7            ]: USB-Audio - Shure MV7
                      Shure Inc Shure MV7 at usb-0000:06:00.3-1.1.3, full speed
```

Non-working XPS:

```
2 [MV7            ]: USB-Audio - Shure MV7
                     Shure Inc Shure MV7 at usb-0000:04:00.0-2.1.4, full speed
```

`sudo inxi -SA`

Working Thinkpad:

```
System:    Host: thinkpad Kernel: 5.10.13-051013-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor 
           driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x 
           Device-3: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-4: Logitech OrbiCam type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
           Device-5: Lenovo type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
           Device-6: Shure EMV Smartcard Reader type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.13-051013-generic
```

Non-working XPS:

```
System:    Host: xps Kernel: 5.11.0-051100-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 5
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)  
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci  
           Device-2: Logitech OrbiCam type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo  
           Device-3: Lenovo USB2.0 Hub type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid  
           Device-4: Shure type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid  
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-051100-generic
```

`sudo lshw -C multimedia`

Working Thinkpad:

```
  *-usb:1
       description: Audio device
       product: Shure MV7
       vendor: Shure Inc
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@4:1.1.3
       version: 0.02
       capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

Non-working XPS:

```
  *-usb:1
       description: Audio device
       product: Shure MV7
       vendor: Shure Inc
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@5:2.1.4
       version: 0.02
       capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

`dpkg -l | grep alsa`

Working Thinkpad:

```
ii  alsa-base                                     1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                        all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-topology-conf                            1.2.2-1                                     all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.5                            all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                    1.2.2-1ubuntu2                              amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  libsox-fmt-alsa:amd64                         14.4.2+git20190427-2                        amd64        SoX alsa format I/O library
```

Non-working XPS:

```
ii  alsa-base                                     1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                        all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-topology-conf                            1.2.2-1                                     all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.5                            all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                    1.2.2-1ubuntu2                              amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

I then installed the `libsox-fmt-alsa` package on the XPS, but that didn't help.

`grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Working Thinkpad:

```
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
```

Non-working XPS:

```
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
```

I also ran the command `dpkg -L linux-modules-<version>-generic | grep snd` on the two machines, output to a file, scrubbed the kernel version, and diffed the output. The only differences are that the XPS has more kernel modules loaded than the Thinkpad. Here's the cleaned-up diff:

```
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/adi/snd-soc-adi-axi-i2s.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/adi/snd-soc-adi-axi-spdif.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-adau1372-i2c.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-adau1372-spi.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-adau1372.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-lpass-va-macro.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-lpass-wsa-macro.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-nau8315.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-pcm5102a.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-simple-mux.ko
> /lib/modules/.../kernel/sound/soc/fsl/snd-soc-fsl-xcvr.ko
```

I then went through and ran `sudo modprobe -r snd-*` for each of the listed modules and replugged the microphone. The dmesg failures still stream through in the same way.

`udevadm monitor -u`

Working Thinkpad:

```
UDEV  [215394.300375] add      /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [215394.390245] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.394469] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.394585] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.396165] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.396764] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.397311] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.397745] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.0/sound/card4 (sound)
UDEV  [215394.398833] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.399652] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.400337] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.00A3 (hid)
UDEV  [215394.400933] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.00A4 (hid)
UDEV  [215394.402051] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.0/sound/card4/pcmC4D0p (sound)
UDEV  [215394.402290] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.3/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [215394.403642] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.0/sound/card4/pcmC4D0c (sound)
UDEV  [215394.405980] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.00A4/input/input218 (input)
UDEV  [215394.406090] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.00A3/hidraw/hidraw8 (hidraw)
UDEV  [215394.407149] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.00A4/hidraw/hidraw9 (hidraw)
UDEV  [215394.407695] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.00A3 (hid)
UDEV  [215394.409578] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.415733] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.0/sound/card4/controlC4 (sound)
UDEV  [215394.417798] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.455823] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.00A4/input/input218/event22 (input)
UDEV  [215394.457949] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.00A4 (hid)
UDEV  [215394.460696] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.468706] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [215394.472079] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1.4/4-1.1.4:1.0/sound/card4 (sound)
```

Non-working XPS:

```
UDEV  [235.479054] add      /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [236.099173] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [236.104541] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [236.104950] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [236.107060] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [236.107348] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [236.107964] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [236.109051] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.007B (hid)
UDEV  [236.109557] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C (hid)
UDEV  [236.109746] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [236.112068] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1 (sound)
UDEV  [236.116508] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [236.116590] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [236.118343] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C/input/input90 (input)
UDEV  [236.118689] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1/pcmC1D0c (sound)
UDEV  [236.119072] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1/pcmC1D0p (sound)
UDEV  [236.127047] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.007B/hidraw/hidraw4 (hidraw)
UDEV  [236.127116] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C/hidraw/hidraw5 (hidraw)
UDEV  [236.128600] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.007B (hid)
UDEV  [236.131412] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [236.132076] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1/controlC1 (sound)
UDEV  [236.135173] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [236.162197] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C/input/input90/event12 (input)
UDEV  [236.163989] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C (hid)
UDEV  [236.166410] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [236.171088] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [236.172704] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1 (sound)
UDEV  [238.530899] remove   /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [238.532306] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1/pcmC1D0p (sound)
UDEV  [238.532452] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1/controlC1 (sound)
UDEV  [238.532504] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [238.532544] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.007B/hidraw/hidraw4 (hidraw)
UDEV  [238.532876] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1/pcmC1D0c (sound)
UDEV  [238.534155] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [238.534212] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [238.534672] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.007B (hid)
UDEV  [238.535377] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0/sound/card1 (sound)
UDEV  [238.536409] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3/0003:14ED:1012.007B (hid)
UDEV  [238.537504] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [238.537605] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [238.539728] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [238.540881] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [238.543144] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [238.543923] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [238.562540] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C/input/input90/event12 (input)
UDEV  [238.610007] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C/input/input90 (input)
UDEV  [238.610090] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C/hidraw/hidraw5 (hidraw)
UDEV  [238.611055] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C (hid)
UDEV  [238.611641] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4/0003:14ED:1012.007C (hid)
UDEV  [238.612897] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [238.613937] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4/5-2.1.4:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [238.615092] unbind   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [238.616111] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:04:00.0/usb5/5-2/5-2.1/5-2.1.4 (usb)
```

This output then repeats in a loop, much like with the dmesg output.

Comment: Silly question, but you've confirmed the XPS 13 has the most recent firmware from Dell, right? There were some XPS models a few years back (the 9380 specifically) that had issues with the USB-C ports on the left side not working consistently ...

Comment: @Matigo yeah, these issues are present with the most recent 2.0.0 version of the firmware.

Comment: I find it interesting that the same device id is detected as `Shure Inc. EMV Smartcard Reader` on the ThinkPad and `Shure Inc.` on the XPS. I think @Matigo is unto something here with the firmware. Unfortunately Shure's website doesn't list the firmware as being downloadable... https://www.shure.com/en-US/support/downloads/software-firmware-archive/mv7

Comment: Did you manage to test some of what was suggested?

Comment: @ThomasHunterII Welcome to AU, could you check and add to the question the output of: `udevadm monitor -u` from both PC's.

Comment: @wyphan: The microphone did ship with the most recent firmware from Shure

Comment: @user.dz I've added the output from the udevadm command.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a solution method similar to what was used in this question [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)
There, the problem was with sound output. This is related but not the same.

Try using a comparison between systems that work and do not work (as you already started to do).
Check a few informational commands.
I am copying here what was used in that other case.
Some of the tests pertain to both cases.
Minor variations should also help.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
$ lsmod | grep snd
$ dpkg -L linux-modules-<your version>-generic | grep snd
$ inxi -SA
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 1 Audio
$ uname -a
$ lshw -C multimedia
$ dpkg -l | grep alsa
$ grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Please post the output, and also take some time to pinpoint (what you judge as) meaningful differences and indicate them, so others can help you better.

You may be missing a package, driver, etc.
If you are lucky, it is only a `linux-modules-...` package.

Comment: I did previously go through and, using `lsmod` and `modprobe`, load a bunch of modules that were present on the Thinkpad and unload a bunch of missing modules (thinking there might be a conflict) on the XPS but without success. Over the weekend I'll try the other commands you've recommended.

Comment: I added the output from your suggested commands to my question.

Answer (score 0):

First, the MV7 worked fine on my desktop pc using Ubuntu (18.04).

After I re-plugged some USB devices, I had similar issues: connecting/disconnecting loop with the message:

```
1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
```

Although the (USB) webcam and video streams were stuttering. I reverted the replugging and everything was fine again: The "fix" for me is, using a USB2 and NOT a USB3 slot for the MV7.

Looks like the USB3 issue is not only related to the MV7: https://askubuntu.com/a/1199300.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 15 9550 and was facing the same issue where the mic would reboot infinitely.

Based on [on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1295311/834994), it seems the problem is PulseAudio communicating with the mic in a way that makes the mic's firmware crash.

I replaced PulseAudio with PipeWire and now the MV7 works perfectly. I used the following PPA: https://github.com/pipewire-debian/pipewire-debian#1-ppa-configuration

Be sure to follow the instructions about disabling the PulseAudio service and give the system a reboot after the fact.